# Graphing a configuration / arrangement of 14 points

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I am trying to create the following arrangement / configuration of 14 points (including the labels):

[image]

I am not able to do this, I've attempted the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        {
            \foreach \y in {0,...,2}
            {
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
        \foreach \x in {0,5}{
            \foreach \y in {1}{
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
        
        % lines
        
        

        % labels
        
        \node[right] at ($(circ-5-1) - (0,0.5)$) {$\mathrm{R_2}$};
        \node[right] at (circ-5-1) {$\mathrm{L}$};
        \node[right] at ($(circ-5-1) + (0,0.5)$) {$\mathrm{R_1}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

which just gives me this configuration instead (I am not sure how to "shift" the lines of points $R_1$ and $R_2$):

[image]

I know the hand drawn picture is placed vertically instead of horizontally, but I would like the lines of points in the arrangement be horizontal. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,y={(0cm,-1cm)}]
\foreach \y in {0,1,2}
{% lines
  \draw[red] (0,\y) -- (11,\y);
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmin{\y*\y-5*\y+7}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xmax{-\y*\y-\y+10}
  \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}
  {% dots
    \node(circ-\x-\y) [draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (\x,\y) {};
  }       
}        
% labels
\node[right] at (11,0) {$\mathrm{R}_1$};
\node[right] at (11,1) {$\mathrm{L}$};
\node[right] at (11,2) {$\mathrm{R}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** Another option is to provide the `\xmin`and `\xmax` values (position of the first and the last dot in each line), instead of calculate them.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,y={(0cm,-1cm)}]
\foreach \y/\xmin/\xmax in {0/7/10, 1/3/8, 2/1/4}
{% lines
  \draw[red] (0,\y) -- (11,\y);
  \foreach \x in {\xmin,...,\xmax}
  {% dots
    \node(circ-\x-\y) [draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (\x,\y) {};
  }
}
% labels
\node[right] at (11,0) {$\mathrm{R}_1$};
\node[right] at (11,1) {$\mathrm{L}$};
\node[right] at (11,2) {$\mathrm{R}_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make this slightly smaller?

Comment: @polygonlink1, I forgot the `scale=0.5`. I'll edit in a moment.